# Como fazer AJAX COM JQUERY enviando um POST?

Tags: jquery, ajax

Oi quero enviar Dois valore, um via Post e um via GET para o meu `funcoes.php`
nesse post quero enviar como get o tipo de solicitação para validar la na funções e também a data que o cliente selecionou do calendario. via POST

Como faço?

```
 $('#agenda_profissional_online').datepicker().on('changeDate', function(e) {

        var agendaData = $('#agenda_profissional_online').datepicker('getDate');
        agendaData = agendaData.toLocaleDateString("pt-BR");
        $.ajax({url: "funcoes/funcoes.php?solicitacao=HORAS_DISPONIVEIS", success: function(result){


        }});

    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use as [opções do Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) `method` (v1.9+) ou `type` (até v1.8) com o valor `"post"` e envie o valor via `data`:

```
$('#agenda_profissional_online').datepicker().on('changeDate', function(e){
   var agendaData = $('#agenda_profissional_online').datepicker('getDate');
   agendaData = agendaData.toLocaleDateString("pt-BR");
   $.ajax({
      data: {agendaData: agendaData},
      method: "POST",
      url: "funcoes/funcoes.php?solicitacao=HORAS_DISPONIVEIS",
      success: function(result){
      }
   });
});
```

A variável `solicitacao` será enviada via GET, e a `agendaData` via POST.